# Sometimes getting nil while converting UTC date string to timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, utc

Sometimes I am getting nil while converting date string to timestamp.

Here is my code:

```
class func createTimeStampFromDateString(dateString : String) -> Double? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    let timeIntervalsince1970 = convertedDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
    return timeIntervalsince1970
}
```

Could you please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing wrong if `dateString` is an ISO8601 date string including fractional seconds and time zone

Comment: For what `dateString` do you get `nil` value?

Comment: Datestring: 2020-06-02T13:38:31.814Z

Comment: That string doesn't produce `nil` for me?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I get this error in run time. But from backend I get detesting format like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ". But before the code was like this : let timeIntervalsince1970 = convertedDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 ( force unwrapped), that's why the app crashed sometimes.

Comment: I didn't get this issue in my device. This issue happened in other device. I got crash report that crash happened in this line: let timeIntervalsince1970 = convertedDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 ( when it was force unwrapped).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the bug is not because of this function (it is working as expected). The bug (the crash) you're experiencing is because you're force unwrapping a date value that is `nil`, and that is because the string used to create that date isn't in the valid format. And this is the nature of working with dates and strings from sources outside of your app—the strings aren't guaranteed to be in the right format. And this is why your function, as it should be, returns an optional value.

By the way, you could simplify your method and take advantage of the `ISO8601DateFormatter`:

```
func timestamp(from string: String) -> Double? {
    let df = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    df.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
    return df.date(from: string)?.timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

And to use it properly, use it conditionally without force unwrapping:

```
if let interval = timestamp(from: "2020-06-02T13:38:31.814Z") {
    print(interval)
}
```

To correct your bug:

1. Don't force unwrap when working with date/string conversions. If the string is ever not in the correct format, consider discarding the result, providing a default value, displaying something like "unknown"—anything but forcing the app to crash.
2. Determine why the string isn't in the right format and see if that's correctable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give me an idea why that dete string is coming in incorrect format?

Comment: We are not able to figure out why the date string is coming in different format. It would be very helpful if you give us some ideas.

Comment: @user8591342 what's the source of the string?

Comment: Source is mongo db.

Comment: @user8591342 what I mean is who is responsible for creating that string, someone on your team, a client, a third party data provider (like an API), etc?

Comment: Yes. The backend guy is responsible for creating the string. I get this dete string from an API call.

Comment: @user8591342 talk to that guy and tell him that you two need to have some words

Answer (score -1):

When using the standard DateFormatter for an ISO8601 date, you should set the locale to en_US_POSIX (`dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`) before converting from string.

Also when converting a string to a date it can always happen that the string is in the wrong format (missing or wrong number/character). There are many things that can be wrong here.

But for ISO8601 dates there is a dedicated `ISO8601DateFormatter`. It can handle multiple variants of ISO8601 formatted dates. But it is only available since iOS 10.